# NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged, used in Outlook Add-In, does not fire when network cable is unplugged

Tags: vb.net, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook add-in with behavior that I'd like to modify, depending on whether a networked computer is available.  To check availability, I was hoping to check once when the add-in is loaded, then wire up a handler to System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged.  I have read that this event does not distinguish between real network adapters and adapters for virtual machines, and the like.  As such, once the event is fired, I plan to ping the computer in question, to verify that it is available.

That said, while debugging my add-in, a breakpoint indicates that the event is not firing, even when I unplug my network cable.  My pertinent code is as follows:

```
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Class ThisAddIn

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        Try

            'do an initial check to see if we are online, store result
            drivesAvailable = checkForExcelNetworkDrives()

'code associated with other functionality

            'wire up event handlers
            AddHandler NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged, New NetworkAvailabilityChangedEventHandler(AddressOf LocalNetwork_StateChanged)

'code associated with other functionality
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Then, inside a module (static class), I have the event handler.

```
Public Sub LocalNetwork_StateChanged(sender As Object, e As NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs)

    'when the network state has changed, check to see if we can still access the Excel network drives
    Dim newNetworkState As Boolean = checkForExcelNetworkDrives()

    'if the drive connectivity has changed, throw a new event, to warn the rest of the system to update its behavior
    If newNetworkState <> drivesAvailable Then

        'then call event
        RaiseEvent DriveAvailabilityChanged(Nothing, New DriveAvailabilityChangedEventArgs With {.DriveAvailable = newNetworkState})
    End If

    'update drivesAvailable
    drivesAvailable = newNetworkState

End Sub
```

I haven't gotten to debugging my custom event yet, as NetworkAvailabilityChanged does not appear to be firing.  Could this be because I'm using it in an Outlook add-in?  Other events are wired up in the add-in's Load event, and they are working.  Additionally, I stepped through the AddHandler line, and it appears to execute without exception.

My next step is to set up a timer and just ping the network computer regularly.  I'd rather not resort to that, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have answered my own question.  I have multiple network adapters, included some for virtual machines.  As long any any of them were up, unplugging my actual network did nothing.  Once I disabled all of the other adapters, unplugging my primary network connection caused NetworkAvailabilityChanged to fire.